# frozen starting in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I updated Ubuntu 12.04 from 11.10 and in the begining I did not have any problem, but after some upgrades when I booted Ubuntu 12.04 from the grub it frozen in the starting screen (the UBUNTU word  with the dots). I reinstalled 12.04 many times from the LiveCD and after some upgrades it happens the same including the message (before the starting screen) that the intel graphycs acceleration failed

Answer (score 0):

You might be installing some packages which have conflicts with your graphic card. Check what upgrades you're installing, and uncheck those related to graphic acceleration.